# MOSFET depletion region and diffusion electrons

Tags: mosfet

[image]

As Voltage from Drain-Source increases, this means the Drain voltage increases.
I understand why the depletion region around the Drain increases, since it is more positive minority carriers will fill the holes near the drain creating a region of no charged carrier

If the positive voltage just next to Drain and on the Gate increases, there should be a greater positive charge and therefore more diffusion electrons attracted at that point?

Comment: Anyone please??

Comment: What are the voltages across the Source-Substrate and Drain-Substrate junctions? From the picture, Source, Drain and Substrate are all at 0 V. So the depletion regions aren't different from a depletion region of a PN junction at zero bias. And stop *Anyone please??* begging for answers, it doesn't help in any way.